# AOSP flashed onto Nexus 5x missing vendor libraries? No Camera access?

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-5

I am attempting to install a locally compiled version of the Android Open Source Project to a Nexus 5x device.

```
Android version: 6.0.1
Lunch setting: aosp_bullhead-userdebug
```

Device, unlocked and in fastboot mode gives the following:

```
VARIANT - bullhead LGH791 16GB
BOOTLOADER VERSION = BHZ10p
BASEBAND VERSION = M8994F-2.6.32.1.12
```

I've downloaded and run the vendor extract sh scripts from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/blobs-preview for the Nexus 5x.

This setup compiles and boots the device (pushed using `fastboot flashall -w`, however there is no Camera app (unable to access the internet on the device, so cannot download one and confirm anything. I could push an APK from the machine I suppose) and a dialogue box appears warning of an internal error. I'm getting this error in logcat repeatedly :

```
libc    : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon": cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android13SensorManager13getSensorListEPPKPKNS_6SensorE" referenced by "/vendor/lib/liboemcamera.so"...
```

Some googling leads me to believe this is due to the vendor binaries not actually being complete. Some further searching leads me here https://github.com/anestisb/android-prepare-vendor

I've run this set of scripts on `bullhead-mtc19z-factory-9f649f91.tgz` downloaded from `developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#bullhead` and replaced the `vendor/` directory in my AOSP source tree with the resulting vendor folder, but compiling and booting this just leaves the device stuck in some sort of error loop during boot according to `adb logcat`

Can anyone advise on how to flash this successfully?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for **programming** questions only. General hardware and software questions are discussed somewhere else.

Comment: I'd suggest trying android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking for help fixing a runtime error. But thanks.

Comment: I posted this on android.stackexchange.com and it was suspended as off topic, with the suggestion that I post the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by making a clean repo init for android 6.0.1_r62, downloading that, compiling it and flashing it to the device. The flashed rom now has access to the camera.

I also used the preview binary extract scripts provided by google to generate the vendor/ directory, and in this instance these scripts seemed to pull more files than in my previous tree, I don't know if these scripts have changed very recently or if there was some issue with my existing tree (I had build it for a different android version in the emulator first, then switched).

If anyone can offer a concrete explanation for what happened, I'll accept that as the answer.